# Joomla virtuemart list all products

Tags: php, virtuemart, joomla1.7

I googled lot but failed actually I need to list all my products of all category to be display in a single page.

**Note:** Virtuemart provide option of List all product in search But here I need to create a menu or a page which do the same .

Has anyone have any idea how to do that ? Is any module available for the same ?

Joomla version - 1.7
Virtumart version - 1.9

Any help will be appreciate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try creating a `custom menu` with below link:

`index.php?page=shop.browse&option=com_virtuemart`

It will list all products with pagination

Cheers !